# Wordpress Editor JS Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**The Issue:**
When editing pages or posts, tinymce doesn't load because of this error.

```
editor.min.js?ver=4.7.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.d [as go] (editor.min.js?ver=4.7.3:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (editor.js?ver=4.7.3:43)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
```

**Install Notes:**

1. Wordpress 4.7.3
2. [Church & Events](https://themeforest.net/item/church-and-events-theme-for-churches-and-events/7028545) Theme (Latest Version, fresh
   installed)
3. All Plugins up to date

**Plugins Installed (All Deactivated)**

```
+-------------------------------+----------+--------+---------+
| name                          | status   | update | version |
+-------------------------------+----------+--------+---------+
| akismet                       | inactive | none   | 3.3     |
| check-email                   | inactive | none   | 0.5.2   |
| contact-form-7                | inactive | none   | 4.7     |
| duplicate-post                | inactive | none   | 3.2     |
| duplicator                    | inactive | none   | 1.2.4   |
| easy-wp-smtp                  | inactive | none   | 1.2.5   |
| gravityforms                  | inactive | none   | 1.9.19  |
| groupsengine_plugin           | inactive | none   | 1.0.9   |
| hello                         | inactive | none   | 1.6     |
| iwp-client                    | inactive | none   | 1.6.3.2 |
| layerslider                   | inactive | none   | 6.3.0   |
| limit-login-attempts          | inactive | none   | 1.7.1   |
| login-security-solution       | inactive | none   | 0.56.0  |
| vamtam-love-it                | inactive | none   | 1.0.0   |
| wysija-newsletters            | inactive | none   | 2.7.9   |
| wp_migration-master           | inactive | none   | 1.2     |
| prayerengine_plugin           | inactive | none   | 1.7.5   |
| seamless-donations            | inactive | none   | 4.0.20  |
| seriesengine_plugin           | inactive | none   | 1.8.4   |
| the-events-calendar           | inactive | none   | 4.4.5   |
| the-events-calendar-filterbar | inactive | none   | 4.4     |
| events-calendar-pro           | inactive | none   | 4.4.5   |
| vamtam-push-menu              | inactive | none   | 2.0.11  |
| vamtam-sermons                | inactive | none   | 1.1.0   |
| varnish-http-purge            | inactive | none   | 4.1     |
| woocommerce                   | inactive | none   | 3.0.3   |
| wordpress-importer            | inactive | none   | 0.6.3   |
| wp-database-backup            | inactive | none   | 4.3.7   |
| wp-retina-2x                  | inactive | none   | 4.8.0   |
+-------------------------------+----------+--------+---------+
```

**Debugging:**

1. Disabled all plugins
2. Fresh install of Theme
3. Fresh install of wordpress
4. Switched to default theme (no more error)
5. Contacted theme author (said they could not reproduce)

**Additional Notes:**
The only thing I can think of is its something in the db itself that's causing the issue? Are there any other debugging steps I can try?

I'm using this same theme on other site and it doesn't have the error. So its something specific to the site in question. But a fresh wordpress install, fresh theme, and no plugins puts me at a loss as to how to track it down. Thanks in advance for any tips/help!

**Updated 4/19/17**
On a whim I started with a fresh wordpress install, with only the church and event theme installed. No errors. So one by one I copied the tables from the production site to the new wordpress install using this query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dev_db.wp_users;
CREATE TABLE dev_db.wp_users LIKE production_db.wp_users;
INSERT INTO dev_db.wp_users SELECT * FROM production_db.wp_users;
```

After copying each table, I refreshed the page editor to see if the error happened. As soon as I copied the wp_users and wp_usermeta tables the error happened. So something in one of those tables is causing a js error on the front end? Hmmm..

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? Or using another browser?

Comment: Yes I've done both. I've also tested it in different environments. Linux server and windows development. The error happens whenever I have the db from the production site.

Comment: Have you updated any plugins? Do all plugins have the same version in the other site (which works) and in the new one? Even though you said that you tried with all plugins deactivated..

Comment: Is there any specific code block that triggers this error? In which plugin this 'editor' is? or what exactly that is

Comment: Its erroring in `/wp-admin/js/editor.min.js`. All plugins are disabled and error persists so I'm not sure if its plugin related? See post for new information.

Comment: I really can't understand the problem but have you tried replacing the specific file with the same file of the working server?

Comment: Do tables have the same encoding? and same db engine?

Comment: That's an interesting problem.  Use your dev tools to "Pause on Exception", and then you can have the dev tools "pretty print" the minified script, to help sort out what's going on.  As it appears to be tied to the user table, and it's clearly while you are logged in, have you attempted to go into your user record / profile via WP dashboard and hit "save", to cause it to (maybe) rewrite some of the relevant records for your profile? And, I might compare the known "OK" records against the "Bad" records.  I' guessing that it's likely some meta record that is missing / not set properly.

Comment: @cale_b great suggestion. When I went to do so it wouldn't let me save because my user didn't have a nickname (idk how it didn't since its required?). Once I entered a nickname the error went away. Went to the production site and did the same and that fixed it there as well. Wow what a strange error from not having a nickname!!!

Comment: Glad it worked out! That was a simple solution!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I was banging my head on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My user not having a nickname is what was causing the issue. Going to 'Your Profile' entering a nickname and saving fixed the issue.